# LCMS machines are pinging random computers on company intranet

Tags: firewall, ping, traffic

we have some LCMS AGILENT machines set up in our lab. for some reason they are pinging random computers in our company. every now and then someone on our network will get a windows firewall notification that it blocked some IP address. i dont know what is going on. can anyone help?

some more info: it says SID 23179 MSRPC server service BO detected

Comment: please to be answering immediately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the LCMS systems sending out echo requests or echo replies?  If it's echo replies there could be something on your network sending echo requests with spoofed IP source addresses to your LCMS systems.  If it's echo requests have you checked the software on the LCMS systems for worms or viruses?  It's unfortunate but sometimes the embedded controllers are actually running Windows software that isn't kept up-to-date or protected with anti-virus software.  Even if the embedded controllers aren't running Windows there could be vulnerabilities that are being exploited by malware.

Comment: how can i tell whether it is a request/reply?

Comment: Install Wireshark (http://www.wireshark.org/) on a computer that is getting hit and capture the traffic.